# How transform-painter works in the picture language in SICP

Tags: scheme, image, sicp

[In the picture language in SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.4) I'm having trouble understanding how the `transform-painter` procedure works:

```
(define (transform-painter painter origin corner1 corner2)
  (lambda (frame)
    (let ((m (frame-coord-map frame)))
      (let ((new-origin (m origin)))
        (painter
         (make-frame new-origin
                     (sub-vect (m corner1) new-origin)
                     (sub-vect (m corner2) new-origin)))))))
```

Specifically why the vector subtraction of the edge mappings of the argument frame by the new-origin is necessary. I would have thought the mapping of the new corners, i.e `(m corner1)` and `(m corner2)`, could serve as the new edges of the transformed frame.

I've done some calculation and I want to know where i'm mixed up.
Taking `flip-vert` as an example,

```
(define (flip-vert painter)
  (transform-painter painter
                     (make-vect 0.0 1.0)   ; new origin
                     (make-vect 1.0 1.0)   ; new end of edge1
                     (make-vect 0.0 0.0))) ; new end of edge2
```

let `flip-vert` take as argument a frame with the following dimensions,

> Origin = (0, 0), Edge1 = (4, 0), Edge2 = (0, 4)

Accordingly the mapping formula would become `(0,0) + x(4,0) + y(0, 4)`.

In the case of `flip-vert` the `origin`, `corner1`, and `corner2` passed as arguments to `transform-painter` are `(0,1)`, `(1,1)` and `(0,0)` respectively.

So after placing them in the mapping formula, one after the other, we get the results

> new-origin = (0,0)+0*(4,0)+1*(0,4) = (0,4)
>
> mapped-corner1 = (0,0)+1*(4,0)+1*(0,4) = (4,4)
>
> mapped-corner2 = (0,0)

Now the `transform-painter` takes the final two results and subtracts them by the `new-origin` to build the new frame, resulting in a frame with the following dimensions.

> Origin = (0,4), New-corner1 = (4,0), New-corner2 = (0,-4)

Looking at these points on a coordinate plane the results don't seem right, while the original corner results before the subtractions took place, do. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the attached pic (sorry for my drawing skills :) ).
i have marked as **m corner1** the transformed vector that you say it would suffice as the new
corner for new frame onto which the painter is going to act ( **m corner1** is the **m** coordinate transformation mapped onto **corner1** point).

But observe that this is 
a vector that just "ends" at the right point. You have to translate the origin too in order to get a correct frame. Observe now that the new origin lies at the point **new origin** and that the new corner that you seek (the red one) is indeed the vector difference of the previous two.

[image: the blue frame that lies in the unit square is mapped onto the red frame]

(the pic shows the blue frame that lies in the unit square being mapped onto the red frame)